# when appending a list with math using another list, how do i make the second list the same length as the first ?

Tags: python, list

i am trying to learn python with code academy, and the assignment is to "Write a for loop that populates square_list with items that are the square (x ** 2) of each item in start_list. Then sort square_list!"

the hint says to have a for loop, an append function and a sort function, and i believe i am using those correctly.

```
 start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
 square_list = []

 for start_list in square_list: 
     square_list.append(start_list**2)
     sort(square_list)
 print square_list
```

i get this error message: "Oops, try again! squareList should be the same length as startList! "

I have also tried using square_list.insert(0, start_list**2) but that also gives the same error. 
I would appreciate your help very much since i am stuck

Comment: You've almost reached there! the `for` .. `in` construct is used to iterate through the entire list. But sorting of list is applied not on individual elements, but on the entire list. If you move the sorting part outside the loop, you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

```
for start_list in square_list: 
    square_list.append(start_list**2)
    sort(square_list)
```

On the first line you have `for start_list in square_list:`.  That's saying "I want to do something in a loop for every `start_list` in `square_list`.  The problem is that these are two separate lists.  You want to create a new variable to stand for every item in `start_list`.  The first two lines should be something like:

```
for x in start_list: 
    square_list.append(x ** 2)
```

This is looping through each *value* (`x`) in `start_list` and appending its square onto `square_list`.

The second problem is the line `sort(square_list)`.  This should not be indented, as that makes it execute each time through the loop.  Also, the syntax to sort a list is `square_list.sort()`.  So those three lines should be:

```
for x in start_list: 
    square_list.append(x ** 2)
square_list.sort()
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, i understand what i did wrong now ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over each elements in `start_list`:

```
for item in start_list:            # for each element in `start_list`
    square_list.append(item ** 2)  # add square of `item` in `square_list`

square_list.sort();                # finally sort the list
```

---

or you can use `sorted()` function over `generator` expression:

```
>>> sorted(item ** 2 for item in start_list)
```

Comment: thank you ! it worked. i have a question though, how does python know that item is referring to the data in start_list ? since we never said item = start_list or something.

Comment: That's what the `for` loop does there. It takes each element from teh `list`, and operate over them.

Comment: if i put another list int front and in addition to the start and square list, would the for loop not work anymore ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for?

Comment: i didn't understand why your code works/ what you changed to it

Comment: I'm just iterating over `start_list` instead of `square_list`. The square_list is empty, and you want to populate it using elements of `start_list`. So, you need iteration over `start_list`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you make a mistake in the loop. Try this:

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []

for number in start_list: 
    square_list.append(number**2)


sort(square_list)
print square_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start_list = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]
square_list = []

# Your code here!

for x in start_list:
   square_list.append(x ** 2)
   square_list.sort()
print square_list
```